Main function for uasyncio micropython software IoT
I am building a backend IoT app in micropython on an ESP32, using python 3.9.12 and uasyncio V3.
i want auto_pump() to work in backgoung from when i start the device and the server to wait for client requests.
This is a little piece of code:
import usocket as socket
import uasyncio as asyncio

d = DHT11(machine.Pin(23))
pump = machine.Pin(22, machine.Pin.OUT)

def get_sensor_data():
    #return data from sensors

async def handle_client(client_socket):
    request = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
    print('Request:', request)
    #manage different GET requests
    client_socket.send(response)
    client_socket.close()

async def start_server():
    #start server 
    while True:
        client_socket, client_addr = server_socket.accept()
        print('Client connected from', client_addr)
        await handle_client(client_socket)

async def auto_pump():
    while True:
        pump_state = get_pump_state()
        
        if pump_state == 1:
            pause_duration = get_pause_duration()
            print(f"Pompa spenta per {pause_duration} minuti")
            change_pump_state()
            await asyncio.sleep(get_pause_duration() * 60)
        else:
            pump_duration = get_pump_duration()
            print(f"Pompa accesa per {pump_duration} minuti")
            change_pump_state()
            await asyncio.sleep(get_pump_duration() * 60)

This is the first Main function i built:
async def main():
    pump_task = asyncio.create_task(auto_pump())
    server_task = asyncio.create_task(start_server())
    await asyncio.gather(server_task, pump_task)

asyncio.run(main())

In this way auto_pump() start for the first time, but until i give server a connection it doesn't change pump_value, So i tried this way:
async def run_auto_pump():
    while True:
        await auto_pump()

asyncio.run(run_auto_pump())
asyncio.run(start_server())

but the problem is still the same, SO i tried another solution with loop :
if _name_ == "_main_":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(auto_pump())  
    loop.create_task(start_server())    
    loop.run_forever()

and it doesn't work the same! someone can help me fixing my problems?

auto_pump() should have while loop to work all time. But it may need also some async function (which needs await) to give time for other async functions. Maybe there is await asyncio.sleep(). If auto_pump() will not have await functioon() then it may block all code.

i changed auto_pump() with my actual code, it was commented because of i want only to explain the solution, now it's the complete version

you may have the same problem in handle_client() - it needs some function which uses await - if it will not have it then it will run as normal function (not async) and it will block all code. You may add await asyncio.sleep(0.01) to sleep 0.01 second.

I think I see another problem - server_socket.accept() is blocking code until it get connection. It may need to use select to check if there is new connection without blocking code. OR maybe you should use some http module because they usually use async functions.

MicroPython asyncio: a tutorial

i think i solved the problem using _thread library, because i can use better threading than async and i think it's similar. the solution i adopted is the following:
`def main():
_thread.start_new_thread(auto_pump, ())
start_server()
if name == "main":
main()`
i think it could solve my problems because server run on the main process waiting for client requests and auto_pump start as a new thread when i start the device.
@furas

you may describe it as answer below. And you can mark your answer as accepted. And some time later you can even upvote your answer.

frankly, I was thinking about threads but I wasn't sure if MicroPython has module threading

it doesn't use threading but there is on github an open source library called _thread that works exactly at the same way, now all my code is running trying with curl and i'm building FE using Kivy !!! thanks for help, i hope can rechange
